# Sub-Miniature version of the 12AU7 valve (vacuum tube)

Tags: amplifier

I want to make my own valve amplifier, and for that, I'll be using an [12AU7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12AU7) dual triode tube. Since the 12AU7 is quite large, is there a sub-miniature version available?

Also: the main difference between the European ECC82 and the American 12AU7 is the heater voltage of either 6.3V or 12.6V. I heard they can be both wired to use both voltages, could someone please explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no significant difference between the ECC82 and the 12AU7 - it's just different nomenclature for the different markets. As for the heater voltage, the two heaters can be connected in series (12.6 V @ 150 mA) or parallel (6.3V @ 300 mA). Parallel is more common since most mains transformers for valve designs have a 6.3V secondary winding. I have no idea whether a sub-miniature version is available.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably subminiature tubes that will work, but submini's tend to have smaller maximum power dissipation and plate voltages.  So you will likely need to re-engineer the circuit, or at least recalculate dissipation. I would suggest finding another medium-mu dual triode on ebay, look at the specs on  http://pw1.netcom.com/~wa2ise/radios/penciltubes.html and see if it will work in your circuit.  For example, the 6111 has low gain like the 12AU7, but dissipation and plate voltages are limited.

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest to anyone to use subminiature tubes instead of highly available 12AU7 or ECC82 if you prefer (or E82ECC). 
Besides this tube is very, very good in hi-fi assemblies and you should not low anode voltage way below 250V, although i made guitar amp with 12V on it's anode.

If you're not familiar with voltage higher then 100, I strongly suggest to use ECC88, very nice (maybe better) double triode which runs beautifully at 90V. And yes, this tube has different heater characteristics (only parallel heaters).

Answer (score 0):

the 12AU7 and other 12A?7 derivatives can be run off a 12-Volt supply. try a google search on DIY headphone Hybrid amplifiers. in addition there are now Low voltage pencil tubes available out of the Former Soviet Union, some of these tubes have a maximum plate voltage of 30 volts, which are designed to be run off battery packs.